# Unity ShaderGraph/Material Property Issue with SetFloat

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

I have the following script attached to a cube in the scene:

```
public class TestShaderGraph : MonoBehaviour 
{
    void Start() 
    {
        Material material = GetComponent<Renderer>().sharedMaterial;
        material.SetFloat("_Min", -.5f);
        material.SetFloat("_Max",  .5f);
    }
}
```

Here is the [shader graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1sARe.png)
Here is the [actual result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZhVl.png) produced when running the scene
Here is the [intended result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3PQ1.png) produced when manually updating the min and max values for the material in the inspector

I also have the lightweight render pipeline asset attached in the graphics settings.
What is it that I am missing here; does anyone now why the values aren't updating on the material?

I also tried outputting the values using:

```
material.GetFloat("_Min");
material.GetFloat("_Max");
```

which does actually result in -0.5 and 0.5 respectively even though it isn't shown on the material.

PSA: While writing out this question I actually found out the solution.
I thought about not posting this but maybe it will help people in the future that also ran into this issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The mistake I made was actually ridiculously simple.
The name of the properties in shader graph are not the reference to the property. The reference is the field labelled 'reference' surprisingly.

[image]

edit: I need to invest in a rubber duck